# Segmentation fault with multidimensional arrays

Tags: c++

I tried searching through this website for possible answers of why this error is occurring but couldn't find the exact answer.

For this little code, I basically have the program read input from a file. (It reads every single character.) Then store it in a multi-dimensional array (2D) and finally print out the array.

This is my code:

```
ifstream file;
char gamemap[20][26];
file.open("maze-hard.txt");
if(!file.is_open())
{
    cout << "Error: Cannot open file" << endl;
    return 0;
}

    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) 
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 26; i++)
        {
            gamemap[i][j] = file.get();
            cout << gamemap[i][j];

        }
        cout << endl;
    }
```

It was somewhat successful, but I got a segmentation fault error. I don't know where the problem lies. Don't go hard on me for this one. I'm not all that advanced in C++.

Comment: 3 steps to help you find the error: 1) compile your code with the `-g` flag; 2) run with `gdb` (in cmd line: `gdb a.out`; and inside gdb: `r`); and 3) when it segfaults, type `bt` in the gdb prompt, it will tell you where your code segfaults.

Answer (score 3):

```
 for(int j = 0; j < 26; i++)
```

I'd replace that `i++` with a `j++`.

Answer (score 1):

increment j in the second cycle, not i ;)

Answer (score 1):

While probably not strictly related to this particular segfault, I'd also check to make sure that the read is good for safety.

```
if(file.good())
{
    gamemap[i][j] = file.get();
    //etc etc
}
```

Comment: While completely correct and valid, this is not an answer to the question itself and as such should be a comment on the original question.